# Make keyboard show up without TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, focus

Is there a command in Flutter to make the onscreen keyboard on mobile devices appear? I am aware of using `FocusNode`s to get the keyboard to show for `TextField`s but I have a situation that does not use any `TextField`s and I would still like to be able to open and dismiss the onscreen keyboard.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Here's the piece of code I'm using. It's being called on the `onPointerDown` callback of a Listener widget

```dart
void handleTap(PointerDownEvent pointerDownEvent) {
    // Get input focus
    _keyboardFocusNode.requestFocus(); // Works fine

    print("In callback"); // Prints fine

    // Bring up keyboard 
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.show'); // Nothing happens
...
}
```

I'm testing this on the iOS simulator. I have hardware keyboard unchecked (to use the software keyboard instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to show Keyboard use:

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.show");
```

And to hide it:

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.hide");
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working... I'm calling it in a callback function attached to a listener widget (listening for tap gestures). When ran in the iOS simulator, nothing happens when I call for the keyboard to open. Any ideas?

Comment: @Microbob Before coming to opening the keyboard, add a print to your Listener callback, does it print?

Comment: Yeah it prints just fine, except no keyboard shows up. I added a code snippet to my question to show what I'm doing.

Comment: Something appears to be forcing it to stay closed. I just tried to force open the keyboard in the simulator and it registers a null key click event (implying it opened but then closed). Is this is any way related to the fact that I don't have any text fields in my scene and therefore I'm not allowed to open a keyboard?

Comment: @Microbob maybe try it on a real iphone.